# Zend newbie - logic based on URL

Tags: zend-framework, url, parameters, zend-route

url is:
http://mySite.com/adminusers/listusers/

my controller is called

public function listusersAction()

```
http://mySite.com/adminusers/listusers/regular      
http://mySite.com/adminusers/listusers/premium
http://mySite.com/adminusers/listusers/excecutive
```

How can I capture last piece of the URL as a paremter in controller file listusersAction?

thanks

Comment: please make more elaborate your question ..its not clear what you actually want to ask?

Comment: do you want to extract "regular" ,"premium", "executive"from URL?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use regex routes for that kind of thing. For example, you could setup a route with the following definition :

```
routes.adminusers-listusers.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex"
routes.adminusers-listusers.route = "adminusers/listusers/(\w+)"  
routes.adminusers-listusers.defaults.controller = adminusers
routes.adminusers-listusers.defaults.action = listusers
routes.adminusers-listusers.map.1 = "usertype"
routes.adminusers-listusers.reverse = "adminusers/listusers/%s"
```

Then, on your controller, you can access usertype by querying the request params :

```
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
$userType = $params['usertype'];
```